# Why is Android throwing invocationtargetexception when reflection into activityManagerNative setAlwaysFinish()

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm trying to perform a reflection to turn off the developer option Don't Keep Activity in the device's system menu. The setting is aka setAlwasyFinish(). I know for some devices you can use

```
Settings.System.putInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES, 0);
```

(I've used this succesfully on 4.0 devices.)

But I am working with a 2.3 device, This device is unrooted. I am under the impression that the reflection would work to modify the setting.
When I perform the code below I receive the exception

> an exception occurred java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception.

Could someone explain to me what I did wrong with my code that I'm receiving this error. Thank you

```
Class<?> activityManagerNative = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");
Method methodDefault = activityManagerNative.getMethod("getDefault"); 
final Method  methodSetAlwaysFinish = activityManagerNative.getMethod("setAlwaysFinish", new Class[]{boolean.class});
Type[] params = methodSetAlwaysFinish.getGenericParameterTypes();
final Object objectInstance = methodDefault.invoke(null);
methodSetAlwaysFinish.invoke(objectInstance,  true);
```

These are the permissions I am using.

```
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some serious digging during debug but the activity required a permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH"/>
```